# Did Anakin’s childhood friends hear of Luke Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars

In *The Phantom Menace* Anakin Skywalker had friends who were Kitster and Wald, and had associates like Watto, Amee, Melee and Seek. Then Anakin left Tatooine to become a Jedi after he was rescued by Jedi Master Qui-Gon Jinn, and we don’t see Anakin’s friends or associates in *Attack of the Clones*, except for Watto.

Many years later did Kitster, Wald, Watto, Amee, Melee and Seek or their children hear of a Luke Skywalker in Tatooine?

Comment: Skywalker's a pretty common name (apparently). If they heard it, they probably didn't think anything of it, any more than you'd be surprised to hear that a John Smith lived near you.

Answer (score 4):

**If they lived enough, probably yes**

In a novel [Bloodline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodline_%28novel%29), written to explain what happened before *The Force Awakens*, it was reveled to general public that real father of Leia is actually Darth Vader. This was done to undermine her chances of becoming [First Senator](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Senator). She then publicly admitted that she and her brother Luke were actually children of Jedi knight Anakin Skywalker who was seduced by Darth Side blah blah .... Luke's name was also mentioned in Senate hearings, some of the Senators doubted his integrity etc ...

From all of this we conclude that Luke Skywalker was well known figure in SW universe, even Rey and Finn knew about him . Considering that story of Anakin Skywalker became public, it is quite possible that his childhood friends did know who his son was.